# Illegal assignment from Decimal to Integer error

Tags: apex, batch

I am getting `Illegal assignment from Decimal to Integer` error for the code

`Integer maxEmailsSentPerDay = tpfs.Maximum_Emails_Per_Day__c;`

where `Maximum_Emails_Per_Day__c` is a number(18,0) field from a custom setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [API Data Types and Salesforce Field Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/api_ui_datatype_map.htm)

> Generally, API data types and field types in the user interface have
>   the same names. For example, a date field is represented by a date
>   data type in the API. However, some field types are represented
>   differently depending on whether you are inspecting an object via the
>   API or the user interface.

So, in your case even though your field type is set as `Number(18,0)`, the API data type for it is `Decimal` i.e. although on interface it will be displayed as `Integer` its actual API data type will be `Decimal`, so it will be considered as `Decimal`

Similarly `Currency`, `Formula`, `Number`, `Percent`, and `Roll-up summary` types are considered as `Decimal` i.e. their API data type is `Decimal`.

Hence when you try to assign any of the above types to an `Integer`, you will have to typecast it or parse it. So, in your case, you can use any of the methods to either typecast or parse your field's value

```
Integer maxEmailsSentPerDay = Integer.ValueOf(tpfs.Maximum_Emails_Per_Day__c);
```

or

```
Integer maxEmailsSentPerDay = tpfs.Maximum_Emails_Per_Day__c.intValue(); //also check for null
```

or

```
Integer maxEmailsSentPerDay = (Integer) tpfs.Maximum_Emails_Per_Day__c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Integer maxEmailsSentPerDay = Integer.ValueOf(tpfs.Maximum_Emails_Per_Day__c);
```

Comment: Just for Curiosity, both the variable and field were of number data type. what was the reason behind the error?

Comment: @AdityaPhadke The other answer goes in to much better detail--you may want to give that one a read. Also why it's a good habit on here to wait a bit before accepting the first answer, as given a bit of time, a better one might come along.